# How to get the value of an html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery code :

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
            function displaySelected(elem){
                var value = $j(elem).find(".columnToHide").html();
                console.log(value);

            }
```

The out put of this is : `<div class="hiddenId" data="a05o000000V88VFAAZ"></div>`.
However, I would like to only get the value in the data tag i.e. the id. I know you can do something like this..

```
.html("<div class='hiddenId' data='a05o000000V88VAAAZ'></div>")
```

but this doesn't strip the tags. Any help please

Comment: So are you trying to get just `a05o000000V88VFAAZ` as your output?

Comment: console.log($(value).attr('data')); // a05o000000V88VAAAZ

Comment: the above works but how cn i assign the output value to a variable? also could you post this as an answer so i can mark it @ThiagoCustodio

Comment: figured it out.. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will drill down to the content you want:

```
$(value).attr('data')
```

To put in context of the rest of your script:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
function displaySelected(elem){
    var value = $j(elem).find(".columnToHide").html();
    console.log($(value).attr('data')); // a05o000000V88VAAAZ
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery's `.attr()` method. So: `$j(elem).find(".columnToHide").attr("data")`

Comment: i tried this but it is outputing "undefined".. not exactly sure why

Comment: The main point of my answer is that you should use `attr()` to access the value of any html data attribute with jquery. If you are getting undefined, please revise whatever method you use to find the DOM element (in this case, revise `$j(elem).find(".columnToHide")` to point to the element you actually want.

Comment: yes. but i figured it out thx. check the comments below my question

Comment: Yes I just figured that since my solution worked you'd accept it as your answer ;P.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method to retrieve the value. (Your data attribute should probably take the form of `data-name` if you have control over that.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
function displaySelected(elem) {
    var value = $j(elem).find(".columnToHide").attr("data");
    console.log(value);

}
```